# LINQ create new list from elements of outer and inner list

Tags: linq

Please see a rough code snippet of what is required.class A is outer class which has three inner lists of type B.

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> var1;
    public List<B> var2;
    public List<B> var3;
    int x;
    int y;
}

public class B
{
    public string strA;
    public string strB;
    public string strC;
}

// This is the new class which i want  as output      
public class C
{
    public string strC1;
    public string strC2;
    public string strC3;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public bool direction;
}

List<A> ListA = SomeClass.GetData( );
List<B>  ListB= new List<B>();
List<C> ListC = new List<C>();

foreach(A myA in ListA)
{
    ListB = myA.var1;
    foreach(B mydata1 in ListB)
    {
    C var = new C();
    var.strC1 = mydata1.strA;
    var.strC2 = mydata1.strB;
    var.strC3 = mydata1.strC;
    var.x = myA.x;
    var.y = myA.y;
    var.direction = true; //if input it is true
    ListC.Add(var);

    }

    ListB = myA.var2;
    foreach(B mydata1 in ListB)
    {
    C var = new C();
    var.strC1 = mydata1.strA;
    var.strC2 = mydata1.strB;
    var.strC3 = mydata1.strC;
    var.x = myA.x;
    var.y = myA.y;
    var.direction = true; //if input it is true
    ListC.Add(var);

    }

    ListC = myA.var3;
    foreach(B mydata1 in ListB)
    {
    C var = new C();
    var.strC1 = mydata1.strA;
    var.strC2 = mydata1.strB;
    var.strC3 = mydata1.strC;
    var.x = myA.x;
    var.y = myA.y;
    var.direction = false; //if input it is true
    ListC.Add(var);

    }
}

var grpList = ListC.GroupBy(p => p.strC);
```

My output is ListC which consists of elements of Inner class B and outer class A and final output is grouped.

Comment: can you provide your working code?

Comment: Do you really need to you `var` as object name?

Comment: Its just like an algorithm of what is required.As i have mentioned,this is just a rough code snippet

Comment: I think @huMptyduMpty is asking since this snippet won't compile because `var` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: updated the answer following the additional supplied information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer:
for the flattened target class C

```
public class C
{
    public string strC1;
    public string strC2;
    public string strC3;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public bool direction;
}
```

Just use the SelectMany flattening method and union it a few times...

```
var C1 = A1.SelectMany(p => p.var1, (p,q) => new C(){
    strC1 = q.strA,
    strC2 = q.strB,
    strC3 = q.strC,
    x = p.x,
    y = p.y,
    direction = true
    }
  ).Union(
    A1.SelectMany(p => p.var2, (p,q) => new C(){
    strC1 = q.strA,
    strC2 = q.strB,
    strC3 = q.strC,
    x = p.x,
    y = p.y,
    direction = true
    })
  ).Union(
    A1.SelectMany(p => p.var3, (p,q) => new C(){
    strC1 = q.strA,
    strC2 = q.strB,
    strC3 = q.strC,
    x = p.x,
    y = p.y,
    direction = false
    })
  ).ToList();
```

edit2: just realised I repeated the same function 3 times above. A more succinct way of writing this would be:

```
var fn1 = new Func<A, B, C>( (p,q) => new C(){
    strC1 = q.strA,
    strC2 = q.strB,
    strC3 = q.strC,
    x = p.x,
    y = p.y,
    direction = !p.var3.Contains(q)
    });

var C1 = A1.SelectMany(p => p.var1, fn1
  ).Union(
    A1.SelectMany(p => p.var2, fn1)
  ).Union(
    A1.SelectMany(p => p.var3, fn1)
  ).ToList();
```

edit3 - direction is now false in the above example when coming from the var3 list

Heres an article explaining SelectMany a bit more... http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/selectmany-probably-the-most-p

Comment: Thanks a lot.That's exactly what was required.

Comment: Thanks also for the link provided on SelectMany.

Comment: No worries - also just realised that there is a more succinct way of writing this without repeating the same function 3 times - as shown in the edit above!

Comment: One of the direction var is false.Can you please let know on the modification needed.

Comment: altered it above as requested

Comment: Thanks a lot.One last question: if i do not have a class C defined and want to create a generic object at runtime,What will i need to do.I could do this in the first solution that was provided.

Comment: out of the 2 versions of the solution above you can easily use an anonymous output class in the first version. This isn't possible with the more succinct version, as Funcs have to have all the typeparameters defined for all the input and output parameters. None the less I'd still favour the 2nd version to avoid repeating code, and just define a class within to use (can be a private class within your parent class)

Comment: Thanks again.I was trying to do the same but realized that it would not be possible.I will use the second option.